# How do I add a hover to this css class for a tr?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, html-table

How do I add a hover to this class in my CSS file?  I can add a hover effect when I do not specify this class by using onmouseover, however I want to use both this CSS class and the hover.

```
tr.TableData td
{  
    background-color:white;  
    color:Black;  
    font-family:'Exo', sans-serif;  
    font-size: 16px;  
    height:60px;
    border-bottom:1pt solid #E2E2E8;
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;  
    margin:0px; 
    width:199px;
    font-weight:400;
}
```

This is my table.  It is an ItemTemplate in a listview:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr class="TableData">
        <td style="width: 30%;">
            <table>
                <tr class="NoBorder">
                    <td style="width: 20%;">
                        <img src='<%#Eval("standard_image") %>' alt="" width="80" onerror="this.src='Content/Images/placeholder.png';" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblProductLine" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("product_line")%>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 24%;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblModelNum" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("model")%>' />
        </td>
        <td style="width: 16%;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblSerialNum" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("serial_number")%>' />
        </td>
        <td style="width: 12%; text-align:center;">
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="SelectCategoryButton" CommandName="Select">
                <img id="Img1" runat="server" src='<%#Eval("display_status") %>' alt="" width="20" />
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 18%; text-align:right;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblShipDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("date")%>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: `tr.TableData:hover`? http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/wgse68et/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean a hover effect on the table-cell, then this should work:

```
tr.TableData td:hover {  
    background-color: red;  
}
```

Comment: This works, thank you!! Do you also know how I can change it back after the user takes their mouse off?

Comment: You don't need to do anything about it when the mouse is off the element.

Comment: For some reason my table row turns gray after I hover off...not sure why.

Comment: Doe you have a live example (like JSFiddle).

Comment: Ah, I had accidently left the onmouseout in there.  Thank you for your help!